# How to sort CardViews in a RecyclerView based on a String using a Switch?

Tags: android, list, sorting, arraylist, android-recyclerview

i want to order alphabetically or by popularity a RecyclerView full of cardViews based on a switch , this is what i have done so far :

```
 public class CategoriesRecyclerView extends Activity {
            private List<Categories> categories;
            private RecyclerView rv;
            private Switch categoriesSortingSwitch;
            private TextView switchStatus;



@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.categories_recycler_view);


            rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
            rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

            //HERE I CALL THE METHOD THAT INITIALIZE ALL THE CARDVIEWS WITH IT'S ELEMENTS ISIDE THE RECYCLERVIEW
            initializeData();

            CategoriesAdapter ca = new CategoriesAdapter(categories);
            rv.setAdapter(ca);


            //SWITCH IMPLEMENTATION FOR THE SORTING
            categoriesSortingSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchsortcategories);
            switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testswitch);
            //set the switch to OFF
            categoriesSortingSwitch.setChecked(false);
            //attach a listener to check for changes in state
            categoriesSortingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {



                       if(isChecked){
    //HERE I SHOW A TEXT VIEW WITH THE SWITCH STATUS (WORKS FINE)
                            switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");



    //HERE I TRY TO ADD ELEMENTS TO THE LIST categories ORGANIZED BY THEIR NAME

                        categories.add(new Categories("CARS", "CARS"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("COUSINE", "COUSINE"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("GAMBLING", "GAMBLING"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("GAMING", "GAMING"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("HISTORY", "HISTORY"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("MUSIC", "MUSIC"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("NATURE", "NATURE"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("RANDOM", "RANDOM"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("SPORTS", "SPORTS"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("STUDIES", "STUDIES"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("TECH", "TECH"));




                    }else{
                        switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");


     //HERE I TRY TO ADD ELEMENTS TO THE LIST categories ORGANIZED BY THEIR POPULARITY


                        categories.add(new Categories("CARS", "CARS"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("SPORTS", "SPORTS"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("GAMING", "GAMING"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("GAMBLING", "GAMBLING"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("TECH", "TECH"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("NATURE", "NATURE"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("RANDOM", "RANDOM"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("COUSINE", "COUSINE"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("HISTORY", "HISTORY"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("MUSIC", "MUSIC"));
                        categories.add(new Categories("STUDIES", "STUDIES"));
                    }

                }
            });


            //check the current state before we display the screen
            if(categoriesSortingSwitch.isChecked()){
                switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");



                categories.add(new Categories("CARS", "CARS"));
                categories.add(new Categories("COUSINE", "COUSINE"));
                categories.add(new Categories("GAMBLING", "GAMBLING"));
                categories.add(new Categories("GAMING", "GAMING"));
                categories.add(new Categories("HISTORY", "HISTORY"));
                categories.add(new Categories("MUSIC", "MUSIC"));
                categories.add(new Categories("NATURE", "NATURE"));
                categories.add(new Categories("RANDOM", "RANDOM"));
                categories.add(new Categories("SPORTS", "SPORTS"));
                categories.add(new Categories("STUDIES", "STUDIES"));
                categories.add(new Categories("TECH", "TECH"));


            }
            else {
                switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");






                categories.add(new Categories("CARS", "CARS"));
                categories.add(new Categories("SPORTS", "SPORTS"));
                categories.add(new Categories("GAMING", "GAMING"));
                categories.add(new Categories("GAMBLING", "GAMBLING"));
                categories.add(new Categories("TECH", "TECH"));
                categories.add(new Categories("NATURE", "NATURE"));
                categories.add(new Categories("RANDOM", "RANDOM"));
                categories.add(new Categories("COUSINE", "COUSINE"));
                categories.add(new Categories("HISTORY", "HISTORY"));
                categories.add(new Categories("MUSIC", "MUSIC"));
                categories.add(new Categories("STUDIES", "STUDIES"));
            }

        }

    //HERE IS THE initializeData() METHOD THAT I CALLED BEFORE THAT HAS A NEW LIST THAT SUPPOSEDLY WAS FILLED ALPHABETICALLY OR BY POPULARITY BASED ON THE SWITCH STATUS.

        private void initializeData() {


            categories = new ArrayList<>();

        }
    }
```

At this point it compiles and runs and when the switch status is changed it correctly notifies it on the TextView that i created for that, but nothing happens with the elements of the RecyclerView, they simply stay in the same order for some reason.

Basically what wanted to do was to add the elements directly in the order specified by the switch to the list created in the method initializeData().

How can i make this work they way i want it? 
i didn't use a sorting algorithm because the data is quite small.

Comment: have a look at an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/37101450/3496570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort your `Categories`, then set the sorted list to the adapter powering your `CardView`s, then notify the adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

[This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) will be helpful on how to use `Comparator`s.

Comment: won't it work if i leave it like i have it right now but using the notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Sure, if you have prior knowledge of the 'popularity' you mentioned, then yes.

Comment: i'm not sure where to add the notifyDataSetChanged(), do i have to add it whenever i submit the data in a different order to the List ?

Comment: Exactly. You inform the adapter that the underlying data has changed and it needs to redraw it's views

Comment: Sorry, i'm kinda lost, i don't really know how to use notifyDataSetChanged(); do you have any sample code or can you show me how should i implent it in my case ? Again thank you so much.

Comment: Just categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88950/discussion-between-sebastian-delgado-and-ascorbin).